# create a customised openFileDialog

Tags: ms-access

i have an access program which i have been working on and i want to create a openFileDialog which will show specific folders and files. For e.g. when you click a button, instead of having the dialog showing all the folders and files, it will be given a parameter (folder name) and it will show only that folder. i am trying to achieve something similar to the windows search engine. the reason is that, my program has a folder which contains around 1000 sub folders which contain a documents. each subfolder has the same name as the document it contains. therefore, what i an trying to achieve is that from my Access Form, the user can click a button, and a dialog will pop up showing only the folder which contains the document the user is working on.

is this possible.

i would really appreciate your help thank you

Comment: Why does a user need to see the one document in a folder with the same name. If they click the button, just open the one document automatically based on the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want OpenFileDialog to start in a specific folder?

You can do it like this:

```
OpenFileDialog MyOpenFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
MyOpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\Path\To\My\Selected\Subfolder" ;
MyOpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I think you must be leaving out a lot of code, as OpenFileDialog() is not a built-in Access object, nor an object that is in any of the default Access or Office libraries. You either need a bunch of code you've ommited or some reference you haven't mentioned.

Comment: you may be right there, this generic .NET, I was making the assumption the OpenFileDialog mentioned by the question asker was the same call - I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Access provides Application.FileDialog. If you want to use the ENUM for the dialog type, you'll have to add a reference to the Office Object library, but if you try to use the enum you'll get prompted and Access will add the reference for you. It's not much use, though, as it can otherwise be used quite easily with object variables instead of strongly-typed variables.

To learn how to use it, open the Immediate Window (Ctrl-G), type Application.FileDialog, and hit F1. That explains the basics.

For what it's worth, I was using Windows API code from the Access Developers Handbook before the Application.FileDialog was introduced (with A2002), so I continue to use that. I am pretty sure the functionality is identical, though Application.FileDialog probably has a spiffier interface (I don't know -- I don't use it!).